# Capture 3D image in Java

Tags: java, image

With help of single webcam can I capture a 3D image of an object? How is it possible? Are there any Java libraries that would help me do this?

Comment: How do you propose to do this? Don't physics and optics suggest that this is not possible (regardless of programming language)?

Comment: Since when have you let the laws of physics or optics stop you?! ;)

Comment: http://www.moreinspiration.com/Innovation.aspx?id=4298  Good luck with that :-)

Comment: Why not just buy a 3D camera? Like this one: [link](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=290567186406#vi-content)

Comment: I m developing application for normal users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to use a [Kinect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect) rather than a standard web cam, you could read its depth map using a Java library (like [CLNUI](http://www.pixelnerve.com/v/2010/11/19/clnui-4-java-kinect/)) and use the information to generate a 3D images.

Comment: Here's a [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QrnwoO1-8A) of 3D video capture using Kinect. This is the only remotely similar thing I've heard of.

Answer (score 1):

to take a true 3D image you need 2 perspectives (one for each eye) a standard camera only has 1

the easiest way to do this is take 2 pictures with the camera shifted ~8cm horizontally and use some 3D image stitching to create the 3D image